# Use a variable to access array's elements attribute

Tags: apex

im trying to figure out a way to access a custom metadata objects settings based on what object I pass into the function.

So I have this apex controller that queries a custom metadata object and that object has a couple of fields that are simple checkboxes named after Object, such as Account__c or Opportunity__c. Im calling the controller from an LWC where I pass the objectName. Now I want use the objectName in my controller to access the custom metadata field just for that object

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean checkMetaDataSettings(String ObjectName) {
    List<CustomMetadata> recordList = [SELECT Account__c from CustomMetadata where QualifiedApiName= 'Default'];
    Boolean setting = recordList[0].[ObjectName]; <---?? How do I make this e.g Account__c
    return setting;
}
```

Any ideas? This somehow seems very basic to me but im missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **get** function to get the value

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean checkMetaDataSettings(String ObjectName) {
    List<CustomMetadata> recordList = [SELECT Account__c from CustomMetadata where QualifiedApiName= 'Default'];
    Boolean setting = (Boolean)recordList[0].get(ObjectName);
    return setting;
}
```